# How to stop the while loop? When loop condition is false, the code inside the loop still runs

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

The condition for the while loop is that the input's value is not -1. The goal is to stop the loop when the input is -1, and get the sum of all the entered values excluding -1 as well as the number of values that are not equal to -1.

However, once the input is -1, the sum adds -1 and the i increases by 1 too. I can't figure out why the code inside the loop is still being executed when the loop condition is false (input ==-1)

```
i=0
sum=0
num=0

while num!=-1:
    num=int(input("enter a number:"))
    sum+=num
    i+=1

if num==-1:
    print(sum)
    print(i)
```

When the input is -1, the while loop is expected to stop and the value of sum/i should be the value prior to the input of -1.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your loop body.  What does it do immediately after it inputs `num`?  It adds it to `sum`, without first checking to see if it's `-1`.  It then adds one to `i`.  And *then* it goes back to the top to see if it was `-1`.

You can fix it by moving the loop exit test to the point immediately after you input `num`:

```
while True:
    num=int(input("enter a number:"))
    if num == -1:
        break
    sum+=num
    i+=1
```